# Pitch changing similar to Talking Tom

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using the Dirac library for changing the pitch of recorded sound similar to Talking Tom application. Everything works perfect when I included this library. But I am facing one issue, actually that's not an issue, processing delay. After I record the input audio as .caf file, the same file is processing to convert to .aif which contains the audio of recorded sound with pitch changed. For this process, it's taking some time. So when I record a sound and try to autoplayback, I am getting a delay for playbacking the recorded sound due to this processing of conversion. My requirement is a clone of Talking Tom application, in which the playback is happening immediately after the recording. Am I doing any wrong? If anyone can help me to solve this issue, really helpful. Do I need to send the portion of code I am using.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? Do you still use Dirac library? Thanks